# Fish shell command subsitution

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, fish

Is there a better way to do command substitution in fish shell?

In bash I can do:

```
$ echo $(whoami) 
user

$ echo "I am: $(whoami)" 
I am: user
```

But in fish is looks like I have to do:

```
$ echo (whoami) 
user

$ echo "I am: (whoami)" 
I am: (whoami)

$ set who (whoami); echo "I am: $who" 
I am: user
```

Is that the recommended way to do command substitution in fish where the substitution needs to happen inside a quoted string?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could just pull the substitution out of the quotes

```
echo "I am:" (whoami)
```

---

To bring this answer up to date: fish 3.4 introduced `$(...)` command substitutions that are expanded within double quotes

```
echo "I am: $(whoami)"
```

[Command substitution](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/language.html#command-substitution)

Comment: ah that makes sense. And I assume if you want it to be in the middle of something you  could do echo "I am: " (whoami) ", hello world!". Its interesting that it interprets the whitespace between the string and the command as a literal space.

`echo "I am:" (whoami) ", hello world!" => I am: user , hello world!`
`echo "I am:"(whoami)", hello world!" => I am:user, hello world!`

Comment: that's just the way echo works: echo joins it's arguments with a space

Comment: That's also why this isn't a good answer. There are other reasons to be putting a subshell within a string than using `echo`. I found this looking for a way to use command substitution in an argument to `bash -c`. Is there an answer for those use-cases?