# how to make command substitution in fish shell?

Tags: shell, fish

in bash or zsh I can write

```
clang++ main.cpp -g -o bin/main `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
```

how can I translate this to fish shell?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot understand command substitution in Fish shell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3281220/cannot-understand-command-substitution-in-fish-shell) or [fish shell command substitution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22537730/fish-shell-command-subsitution)

Comment: well, I already checked them out , and they didn't answer my question.

Comment: The documentation: http://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html#expand

Answer (score 5):

fish uses parenthesis for command substitutions.

```
clang++ main.cpp -g -o bin/main (pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv)
```

note that parenthesis nest nicely, unlike backticks!

Comment: For what it's worth, `$(command)` is the recommended syntax in the POSIX shell, and `\`command\`` is long since deprecated.